# Media upload not working on theme option in WordPress 3.8.1

Tags: plugins, uploads, media, theme-options, media-modal

I have this jQuery code in my plugin to display a media box preferably to upload an image or to pick an image from the media gallery:

```
(function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();

});

});
})(jQuery);
```

and thee are the following elements in my plugin option that binds with that jQuery code:

```
<input class="nput" id="upload_image" type="text" name="the_box[authorpic]" value="<?php echo $options['authorpic']; ?>" />&nbsp;<input class="button-primary" id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Pick From Gallery" />
```

but now it doesn't work, I mean nothing happens when I click or press the button now as it should display the media box just like before (I'm using now WordPress 3.8.1) and I'm sure I load up the jQuery scripts (I tested it).

What could cause this not to work any more? Any ideas, recommendations and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please start following up on your old questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `(function($){` from the beginning and `})(jQuery);` from the end. And change `jQuery(document).ready(function()` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`